# Retrieve value of child key in multidiensional array without knowing parent key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Given this multidimensional array, I'm trying to retrieve the value of one of the child keys:

```
$movieCast = Array(
    '1280741692' => Array(
        ...
        , 'userid' => 62
        , 'country_id' => '00002'
        ...
    )
    , '1280744592' => Array(
        ...
        , 'userid' => 62
        , 'country_id' => '00002'
        ...
    )
)
```

How can I retrieve the value of `country_id`?

The top-level array key could be anything and the value of `country_id` will always be the same for a specific user. In this example, user #62's `country_id` will always be `00002`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate through the outer array:

```
foreach ($outer as $inner) {
    //do something with $inner["country_id"]
}
```

Another option is to build an array with the `contry_id`s (example uses PHP >=5.3 functionality, but that can be worked around easily in earlier versions):

```
array_map(function ($inner) { return $inner["country_id"]; }, $outer);
```

**EDIT** If the ids are all the same, even easier. Do:

```
$inner = reset($outer); //gives first element (and resets array pointer)
$id = $inner["country_id"];
```

Comment: i just need the id not the list of country id bcoz all country id are same?

Comment: why we use foreach, i don't want to looping. i just want first array country_id, foreach took time if array is too large( actually it is session array)

Comment: @Just It would work, but it's less simple than just `$inner = reset($outer); $id = $inner["country_id"];`. Why would you want to make a loop that does only one iteration. always.

Comment: @Artefacto Thankyou for help.. i was using foreach unnecesarily.thanks

Answer (score 1):

a more general-purpose solution using php 5.3:

```
function pick($array,$column) {
    return array_map(
        function($record) use($column) {
            return $record[$column];
        },
        $array
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
array_column($movieCast, 'country_id')
```

The result will be:

```
array (
    0 => '00002',
    1 => '00002',
)
```